# Element aligment in a navbar

Tags: html, css, alignment

Today I tried to create a navbar for my new site

Would be formed by two parts, one of 15% and a width of the remaining 
I tried to make the height with the padding, but I have several problems when I **align** the contents of the nav.

http://jsfiddle.net/MKY3r/

```
.main-nav {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, green, green 15%, red 15%, red);
  padding : 15px;
}

.main-nav .logo {
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
}

.main-nav .nav-content {
  width: 85%;
}
```

As you can see, it should be a fairly simple problem but I can not understand the solution

I hope you can help me, **thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

Add `{display:inline}` to the paragraph in .nav-content

Code:

```
.nav-content p {display:inline;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MKY3r/5/)

I would suggest using some heading element in your .nav-content, for example h1 instead of p

[Demo with H1](http://jsfiddle.net/MKY3r/6/)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but unfortunately your solution to a problem. 
In this example I would like navbar with fontawesome add icons, but they do not respect the div : http://jsfiddle.net/MKY3r/7/

I hope you can help me

Comment: Try to set `.input-group {display:inline-block;}` in your css, div's are block elements by default and that means they render on the whole width of the parent element. That's why your icons are on separate rows. Check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/MKY3r/8/

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much for your help. You deserve the best answer. 

Just one question: I tried to apply to my case your solution, but I still have some problems. 
Here I inserted the code in question so that you can give me the 'last help. http://jsfiddle.net/MKY3r/9/

Thanks again

Comment: You are mixing float with inline elements, so when using float, you have to clear this float. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/MKY3r/10/ - I added clearfix styles that you can use on all container elements, which contain floating elements. That clears the floats inside. In your case `<div class="main-nav clearfix">`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in this way, however, as you can see, the background does not take more than the 'height of the content

Comment: What do you mean with "background does not take more than the 'height of the content"? The background takes all the height of the content on my example http://jsfiddle.net/MKY3r/10/ Which browser are you using?